# Error: Unknown argument: standalone when trying to generate standalone Angular component with the Ionic CLI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, command-line-interface

When I try to generate a standalone component using the Ionic CLI, I get the following error:

```
$ ionic g c someComponent --standalone
> ng generate component someComponent --standalone --project=app
Error: Unknown argument: standalone
```

I'm using:

```
"@angular/core": "^17.0.8",
"@ionic/angular": "^7.7.3",
...
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
"@ionic/cli": "^6.20.9",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with my `@ionic/angular-toolkit` version. After upgrading to `"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.1"` it works just fine.